# Loop through array of objects, filter based upon whether date is in current month

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Mongoose Schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  creditCard: String,
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }],
});
```

I then have a React front-end, which initiates an empty array, and sets the response as state:

```
this.state = {
      debts: []
    }
```

I then want to filter through this array, and if creditCard === true, save them in a variable:

```
  const creditCards = this.state.debts.filter((x) => { return x.creditCard === 'true' })
```

Next, I map through each of the remaining objects in the array, take their 'balance' object out, and save them in another variable:

```
const databaseBalance = creditCards.map(x => x.balance)
```

If I console log databaseBalance, this is the output:

> [[{_id: "5fc4aa02959b1409f2edab69", newBalance: 300, balanceDate:
> "2020-11-30T08:14:58.035Z"}, {_id: "5fc51cb0bd4d9a0f6059bdbe",
> newBalance: 400, balanceDate: "2020-11-30T16:24:14.390Z"}]]

What I then want to do, is look at each of the balanceDate entries, compare them to a certain month (current month, then current month - 1, current month - 2 and so on), and then store them in the following variable:

```
const currentMonthValues = []
const currentMonthValuesMinusOne = []
const currentMonthValuesMinusTwo = []
```

For reference, the balanceDate entries are stored as date objects, like so:

> 2020-11-30T08:14:58.035Z

The entries stored into the empty currentMonthValue have to be full objects - and still contain the 'newBalance' data and so on.

My question is... How do I do this? I've been racking my brain about how to do it, but can't for the life of my figure it out.

Hope all of the above is clear, please say if you have questions.

EDIT: I now have a fix... I just need to reduce the numbers down to a total now.

Here's the working function:

```
const currentMonthCreditArray = creditCards.flatMap(x => x.balance.filter(y => (new Date(y.balanceDate).getMonth() === new Date().getMonth())))
```

What I now need to do is take each of the 'newBalance' from this array, and reduce them into an overall figure.

I tried something like this...

```
const currentMonthFinal = currentMonthCreditArray.flatMap(x => x.balance.map(y => y.newBalance.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)))
```

But it errors out. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter inside your map like so:

```js
const currentMonth = creditCards.map((x) => {
  return { ...x, balance: x.balance.filter((y) => new Date().getMonth() - new Date(y.balanceDate).getMonth() <= 1) };
}).filter(i => i.balance.length);


const lessOneMonth = creditCards.map((x) => {
  return { ...x, balance: x.balance.filter((y) => new Date().getMonth() - new Date(y.balanceDate).getMonth() <= 2) };
}).filter(i => i.balance.length);
```

The date filters probably aren't exactly what you are after but you should get the idea.

---

I love functional programming but this above will do lots of looping. If those arrays are large this might not be a great solution. In that case look at Array.reduce() or good old Array.push()

Comment: Thanks, I feel like this is close..... But I don't think it works as expected - it isn't filtering any of them out. Can you explain what each part does, and the '<= 1' at the end?

Comment: Yeah as mentioned the date filter probably isn't exactly what you want. Date.getMonth() returns the date as an int. So we're seeing how many months difference there is between your date and the current date. If the diff is less than 1 month, less than 2 months etc..

Comment: @JonNicholson answer updated that might better suit your needs. Also order of my date args was wrong. It should filter now

Comment: Thank you for this. The original was closer - it just needed a '- 1', '- 2' etc on the end instead of '<= 1' and so on. I've accepted your answer, but could do with a bit more advice if you'd be willing to help? I've got the arrays now, I just need to reduce them to a total figure! If I update the original question could you help?

Comment: @JonNicholson yeah sure will try help out. I think at that point you  should just be able to use: `currentMonthCreditArray.reduce((a,b) => a.newBalance + b.newBalance, 0)`

After the flatMap the array should only be 1 level deep - so don't try chain .flatMap().map().reduce() - that would need 3 levels of arrays